# Actualizar de info de Botones Paypal con React

Tags: reactjs

Estoy teniendo el problema de actualizar la informacion del los botones creados con el SDK de Paypal en react.
En mi app.js creo la vista con los componentes y uno de estos crea los botones de `Paypal` usando Javascript, al rellenar el monto a pagar que deseo y hacer click en el boton la informacion actualizada del monto no esta llegando, solo la informacion que obtiene de mi api al levantar la vista.

De esta forma estoy llamando el Boton de paypal con react:
En el state tengo la info que viene por api y se la asigno mediante el constructor.

```
<Col xs={12} className="mt-3">
                    <Row className="mt-3">
                        <Col xs={3}>
                        </Col>
                        <Col xs={6} >
                            <ButtonPaypal
                                IdLink={this.state.IdLink}
                                IdCredito={this.state.IdCredito}
                                Dolares={this.state.MontoCargado}

                            />

                        </Col>
                    </Row>
                </Col>
```

En el Componente de texto tengo un evento que actualiza la informacion mediante el evento, y lo cambia correctamente ya que hasta el archivo que contiene los botones de paypal lleva bien la info.

```
EventoIngresarColones(event) {
    this.setState({ MontoCargado: event.target.value });
    console.log('Log:' + this.state.MontoCargado);
}

 <Form.Control placeholder='Ingresar Colones'
                                        id="InputMonto"
                                        onChange={this.EventoIngresarColones}
                                        style={{ backgroundColor: "#d6f0fa", color: "#4ebce9", borderStyle: "none" }} />
```

Aqui en la creacion del boton con JavaScript, que al momento de dibujar estos botones en pantalla obtiene la info que viene de la api pero no la cantidad de dolares que ingreso a mano, entonces esa info no la logro actualizar.

```
    export function ButtonPaypal(IdLink) {
      
      const paypalReferencia = React.useRef();
      React.useEffect(() => {
        window.paypal.Buttons({
          createOrder: function () {
            return fetch(`https://localhost:44386/Api/Paypal/ObtenerPagoPaypal?IdCredito=${IdLink.IdCredito}&Dolares=${IdLink.Dolares}&IdLink=${IdLink.IdLink}`, {
              method: 'post',
              headers: {
                'content-type': 'application/json'
              }
            }).then(function (res) {
              return res.json();
            }).then(function (data) {
              return data.id; // Use the key sent by your server's response, ex. 'id' or 'token'
            });
          }
         }).render("#paypalReferencia");
        },[]);
    
      return <div id="paypalReferencia"></div>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El Hook `useEffect` que se usa dentro de la función `ButtonPaypal`, está configurado para correr el efecto solo una vez:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
   //tu codigo...
},[]);
```

Ahora, lo que se necesita es observar por cambios en la siguiente propiedad del objeto `State`, cada que se introduce algún valor en el `Input` tag:

```
this.state.MontoCargado
```

Luego, dentro del hook `useEffect` en el `query string` de `fecth` dentro de la funcion `ButtonPaypal`, se esta usando `props.Dolares` (IdLink.Dolares):

```
query string....&Dolares=${IdLink.Dolares}
```

Al ejecutar `setState` luego de ingresar datos en el `Input`, se muta el objeto `State`, y se ejecuta el re-render, pero Hook `useEffect` solo se ejecuta una vez, al iniciar la `App`, **pues no tiene dependencias asignadas**.

La sugerencia es configrar `useEffect` con una dependencia, en este caso parece ser que lo que se requiere es saber cuando muta el estado de la propiedad `MontoCargado`:

```
 React.useEffect(() => {
       //tu codigo...
    },[IdLink.Dolares]);
```

De esta forma, el `useEffect` se disparará siempre que la propiedad `IdLink.Dolares` cambie.

Puede que se tenga algún mensaje en la consola relacionado a **missing dependency**, en este momento.

Finalmente, lo correcto sería agregar las 3 dependencias que usa el hook `useEffect`, que son todas las `props` que se pasan en el componente `ButtonPaypal`:

```
<ButtonPaypal
            IdLink={this.state.IdLink}
            IdCredito={this.state.IdCredito}
            Dolares={this.state.MontoCargado}
        />
```

Pues todas estas props están siendo referenciadas como dependencias del hook `useEffect`, en el query string del método `fetch`:

```
fetch(`https://localhost:44386/Api/Paypal/ObtenerPagoPaypal?IdCredito=${IdLink.IdCredito}&Dolares=${IdLink.Dolares}&IdLink=${IdLink.IdLink}`
```

Comment: gracias ya lo pruebo

Comment: Me encuentro con el mismo problema de siempre, que al recargar esos botones, se me duplican los botones, y eso me paso al pasar por el hook esa propiedad.

Comment: ok, ¿Ya puedes ver la cantidad de dolares que ingreso a mano? fue la pregunta principal

Comment: Una observación que puede ser de ayuda, con respecto a como se renderiza el botón, el div que se regresa no tiene la propiedad ref (que viene del hook useRef() que se configuró al inicio del componente), yo la agregaría también: <div ref={paypalReferencia} id="paypalReferencia"></div>, tal vez también se tenga que pasar como expresión {JSx} en el método render de window.paypal.Buttons, tendrías que probar de tu lado, saludos

Comment: Claro como respuesta a la pregunta me sirvio, pero llegue a este problema cuando logre que no se dupliquen los botones

Comment: Si me ha pasado, espero que logres resolver lo de la duplicación, tal vez otra pregunta para la comunidad, suerte y salud!